# $2n \times 2n$ matrices with entries in $\{1, 0, -1\}$ with exactly $n$ zeroes in each row and each column with orthogonal rows and orthogonal columns

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

I am interested in answering the following question:

**Question**

*For a given $n$, does there exist a $2n \times 2n$ matrix with entries in $\{1, 0, -1\}$ having orthogonal rows and columns with exactly $n$ zeroes in each row and column?*

**Conjectures**

1. For $n=2^k$, $k\ge0$ such a matrix always exists.
2. For $n=3$ such a matrix does not exist.
3. For $n=5$ such a matrix exists, for example:
   $$
   \left(
   \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
    0 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & -1 \\
   \end{array}
   \right)
   $$
4. For $n=7$ such a matrix does not exist.

Comment: Do you mean "having orthogonal columns and rows" when saying "orthogonal matrix"?

Comment: Yes, let me update the question accordingly to make it clear.

Comment: Well one observation is that if $A$ satisfies the conditions so does 

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 A & -A \\
-A &  -A
\end{array}
\right)$

So starting with say the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix we get ones of size $2^k$ for all $k$.

Comment: If $H$ is an $n \times n$ Hadamard matrix, then $\begin{bmatrix} H&0 \\ 0&H \end{bmatrix}$ meets the requirements. As a reminder, the Hadamard conjecture says that there is a Hadamard matrix of size $4k$ for every $k$, and this has been checked for $4k \leq 668$.

Comment: Generalizing both Nate and my observations: If $H$ is a Hadamard matrix, and $A$ is one of your matrices, then the Kronecker product $H \otimes A$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product ) is one of your matrices.

Answer (score 14):

There is no such matrix if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$.

Suppose otherwise. Each column represents a vector of length $\sqrt n$. Since those vectors are pairwise orthogonal, their sum is a vector whose scalar square is $2n^2$.

On the other hand, the sum of all columns has odd entries, so their squares are all  congruent to $1$ modulo $8$. Hence the sum of those squares is congruent to $2n$ modulo $8$. Hence we should have $2n^2\equiv 2n\pmod 8$, or $8\mid 2n(n-1)$ which does not hold.

Comment: These matrices are actually a special case of weighing matrices. Weighing matrices $W(n, k)$ are $n \times n$ matrices with entries $\{\pm 1, 0\}$ such that $W^TW = kI_n$, The question is asking about the existence of $W(2n, n)$. So, one alternative proof that there is no such matrix for $n \equiv 3 (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$ is as follows. Suppose  $n \equiv 3 (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$ and there exists $W(2n, n)$. It is known that if there exists $W(2n, n)$ with $2n \equiv 2(\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$ then $n$ must be a sum of two integer squares. This is a contradiction with $n \equiv 3 (\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$.

Answer (score 9):

Your first conjecture was proven by [Nate in the comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421691/orthogonal-2n-times-2n-matrices-with-entries-in-1-0-1-with-exactly#comment1083525_421691).

Your second conjecture is also true - there is no such matrix for $n=3$. If we just look at which entries are nonzero in each row, because any two rows are orthogonal, they must share an even number of nonzero entries, i.e. either share $0$ entries or $2$ entries. Only $3$ other rows can share $2$ nonzero entries with a given row, since otherwise there'd be more than $3$ nonzero entries in a column by the pidgeonhole principle, so $2$ rows must share $0$ nonzero entries, but then they share $3$ entries with each other, contradiction.

Comment: You can go even further: The third conjecture is also true ;-)

Answer (score 8):

$\def\Id{\text{Id}}$A [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) is an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\{-1, 1 \}$ with $H H^T = H^T H = n \Id$. What you want is a matrix $X$ with entries in $\{-1, 0, 1 \}$ with $XX^T = X^T X = (n/2) \Id$.

I will show that, if there is an $n \times n$ Hadamard matrix $H$, then there is also an $n \times n$ matrix $X$ obeying your condition. The proof is simple: Let $S = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} 1/2 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 & - 1/2 \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]$; note that $S S^T = (1/2) \Id_2$. Let $D = \left[ \begin{smallmatrix} S&&& \\ &S&& \\ &&\ddots& \\ &&&S \\ \end{smallmatrix} \right]$ where there are $n/2$ copies of $S$. We take $X=DH$. Since $H$ has entries in $\{ -1, 1 \}$, the matrix $DH$ has entries in $\{ -1, 0, 1 \}$. We have $(DH)(DH)^T = DHH^TD^T = n DD^T = (n/2)\Id_n$ and similarly $(DH)^T (DH) = (n/2) \Id_n$ as desired.

This is useful because Hadamard matrices are extensively studied. Hadamard's conjecture says that there is always a Hadamard matrix of order $4k$ for any $k$. Hadamard matrices are known to exist for $n$ of the form $q+1$ or $2(q+1)$, where $q$ is a prime power which is $3 \bmod 4$ or $1 \bmod 4$ respectively, and in many other cases; see the above cited Wikipedia article.

That's only half of what you want, because your matrices sometimes exist for $n \equiv 2 \bmod 4$, and Hadamard matrices never do, but it seems like progress.