# Conjecture on the existence of centrosymmetric Hadamard matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I work with centrosymmetric matrices and recently have started exploring the question of the existence of *centrosymmetric Hadamard* matrices.

**Definition**: An $n \times m$ matrix $A = (a_{i,j})$ is *centrosymmetric* if $a_{i,j} = a_{n-i+1, m-j+1}$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$, $j=1,\dots,m$.

Denote by $R_n = (r_{i,j})$ the *reverse identity matrix* of order $n$, i.e. $r_{i,j} = 1$ if $j = n - i + 1$ else $r_{i,j} = 0$. Then it is not hard to see that $A$ is centrosymmetric iff $R_n A = A R_m$. When the dimensions of the matrices are clear from the context we write just $R$ instead of $R_n$.

The following two propositions are well-known in the theory of centrosymmetric matrices.

**Proposition 1**:  A square matrix $A$ of order $2n$ is centrosymmetric if and only if
there exist square matrices $B$ and $C$ of order $n$ such that
\begin{equation}
      A = \begin{bmatrix}
        B & R C R \\
        C & R B R
      \end{bmatrix}.
  \end{equation}

**Proposition 2**:  Let $A$ be a $2n \times 2n$ centrosymmetric matrix in the form $      A = \begin{bmatrix}
        B & R C R \\
        C & R B R
      \end{bmatrix}$ for some square matrices $B$ and $C$ of order $n$.
Then there exists
a $2n \times 2n$ orthonormal matrix $Q$ such that
\begin{equation}
    Q^T A Q = \begin{bmatrix}
      B - R C & 0 \\
      0 & B + R C
    \end{bmatrix}.
  \end{equation}

**Definition**: An $n \times n$ matrix $H$ with entries $\pm 1$ is *Hadamard* iff $H^TH = n I_n$.

I propose the following conjecture.

**Conjecture**: *There exists a centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order $4 n$ if and only if $n \not \equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod}\  4)$.*

By first transforming a given centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix into block-diagonal form with Propositions 1 and 2, and then applying the result from the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/421723/199547) to the block-diagonal form, it is not hard to see that $n \not \equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod}\  4)$ is a necessary condition.

On the other hand, by using a variant of [Sylvester's construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Sylvester%27s_construction) I have found centrosymmetric Hadamard matrices of order $2^k$, $k>1$.

Also, by searching for cliques in a variant of [Hadamard graphs](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1007/BF02582929) I have also found centrosymmetric Hadamard matrices of orders 20 and 24.

The most recent open question I am trying to resolve is the following.

**Question**: *Does there exist a centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order 36?*

**EDIT**: The question of existence for $n=36$ is answered positively [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446770/199547). The proposed conjecture stated in the question is *false*. Also, the general question of existence can be rephrased differently. For details, please see my comment [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/445371/199547).

Comment: I have tried an approach through an [ILP program with binary variables](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/9428/9517). Unfortunately, running it at the [NEOS server](https://neos-server.org/neos/) takes less than the maximum allowed time of 8 hours only for $4n \le 24$, for which I have found solutions. If you have a license of a professional LP solver software like Gurobi or CPLEX, or want to try a free alternative like [HiGHS](https://highs.dev/), you could try to make a machine work for much longer and hope to be lucky.

Comment: Please check Robert's comment https://mathoverflow.net/a/435470/199547

Answer (score 5):

The conjecture proposed in my question is *false*. We have the following.

**Proposition**: There is no centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order $n=84$.

**Proof**:
Suppose the contrary, let $H$ be a centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order $n=4k=84$. Then $A$ can be written in the form
$      A = \begin{bmatrix}
        B & R C R \\
        C & R B R
      \end{bmatrix}
$
where $B$ and $C$ are $2k \times 2k$ matrices with entries $\pm 1$.

It is not hard to see that the matrices $\frac{1}{2} (B\pm RC)$ are *[weighing matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_matrix)* $W(2k, k)$
with $k=21$. Note that  $k \equiv 1(\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$. According to [1,2], the existence of $W(2k, k)$ where $2k \equiv 2(\mathrm{mod}\ 4)$ implies that $k$ is a sum of two integer squares. This is a contradiction with the fact
that $k=21$ cannot be written as a sum of two integer squares [3]. Hence, there
is no centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order $n=84$. $\Box$

*Note*: The existence of a single $W(2k,k)$ is not sufficient to guarantee the existence of a centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order $4k$. This follows from the following proposition which is not hard to prove.

**Proposition**: A centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order $4k$ exists
if and only if there exist two disjoint weighing matrices $W(2k, k)$. $\Box$

Note:
We say that two $n \times n$ weighing matrices are *disjoint* if their element-wise matrix product is a zero matrix.

**References**:

1. https://ro.uow.edu.au/infopapers/1022/
2. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-59032-5_2
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem
4. [http://www.math.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~munemasa/research/matrices/data/W-18-9.magma](http://www.math.is.tohoku.ac.jp/%7Emunemasa/research/matrices/data/W-18-9.magma)

Answer (score 3):

this appears to be a variant on a special case of a problem I'd worked on as a PhD student back in 1988 (it appeared in my 1991 thesis and in a brief paper in Ars Combinatoria in 1992).  It's a completely different take but it's easy to see the relationship between them. Also to a problem I'm working on right now (and spoke about in the Kracow meeting this summer) concerning partitions of a Hadamard matrix into $2\times 2$ blocks.  I look at various constraints on those blocks (such as all rank 1 or all rank 2).  your question may be reorganized as asking about those matrices for which this all blocks are *symmetric* rank 1 matrices, that is of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ b&a \end{pmatrix}$.  As it happens I had explored this case in the 1988 work but did not resolve it completely.  But I did find the order 20 case and showed, among other things, that these can be produced in every order $2n$ where $H(n)$ exists, which would subsume your order 24 case.  I think the general case of $H(4q)$ where $q$ is odd (and of course $1 \pmod 4$) is an interesting one that may run very deep.  I have worked on this from time to time over the years and while it's a fruitful question, I can't say I'm anywhere near resolving it.

Feel free to email me at craigenr@umanitoba.ca

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Community bot says this is unclear.  Yeah, ok my answer is in some stuff I've published. I'm happy to send sources to any curious responders ... at the given address ... but not inclined to write out in long form here.

Answer (score 2):

**Question**: *Does there exist a centrosymmetric Hadamard matrix of order 36?*

**Answer**: *YES.*

**Proof**:
More than one centrosymmetric matrices can be constructed by computer.
This is just one example as follows:
$+++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------$
$++---+-+---+--+++-+-+++--+--+---+++-$
$+-+--+-+--+++----+-++--+-++--++--++-$
$+--+-+-++-+-++-++-----+-+++++-++--+-$
$+---+++---+--+-+-++-++-+--+-+-+++---$
$+++++++----+++++---++---++-+++++++--$
$+---++++-++---+-++-+-++-+--++++--+--$
$++++--+++++---+-+++-+--+-+-++++++-+-$
$+--+---+++-++--+--++-+-++---+++-+---$
$+-----+++++---++---++---+++----+++-+$
$+-+++-++-++++++---+---+---+-+-+-++++$
$+++--+--+-++--++-++---+-+-++-++-+--+$
$+-++-+--+-+-+-+---++++++---++--+-+-+$
$+--+++----+--++-+-++---+++---+--+-++$
$++---+++-+++++++-----+-+---+-+-+--++$
$++-+++--++-+--++++-+---+--+-+-++-+++$
$++-+--++-----+-++-+++-++--++-++--+-+$
$+-+-+-++---+---+-+++--++++-++--+--++$
$++--+--++-++++--+++-+---+---++-+-+-+$
$+-+--++-++--++-+++-++-+-----++--+-++$
$+++-++-+-+--+---+-++++--+-++--+++-++$
$++--+-+-+---+-+-----+++++++-+++---++$
$++-+--+---+++---++-+-++--+----+++--+$
$+-+-+--++---++++++---+-+-+-+--+-++-+$
$+--+-++-++-+-+---++-++--++-+--+--+++$
$++++-+-+-+---+---+---++++++-++-+++-+$
$+-+++----+++---++---++---+++++-----+$
$---+-+++---++-+-++--+--++-+++---+--+$
$-+-++++++-+-+--+-+++-+---+++++--++++$
$--+--++++--+-++-+-++-+---++-++++---+$
$--+++++++-++---++---+++++----+++++++$
$---+++-+-+--+-++-++-+-+--+---+++---+$
$-+--++-+++++-+-----++-++-+-++-+-+--+$
$-++--++--++-+--++-+----+++--+-+--+-+$
$-+++---+--+--+++-+-+++--+---+-+---++$
$---------+++++++++++++++++++++++++++$

Here, $-$ stands for $-1$ and $+$ for $+1$.

**References**:

1. https://blog.csdn.net/mcs_liyun/article/details/130665503

Comment: This is indeed a centrosymmetric Hadamard of order 36. Thank you for this! Could you perhaps describe in more detail the method you used to find it?

Comment: I think the most elegant construction method for order 36 is from The Encyclopaedia of Design Theory edited by Peter J. Cameron.

Comment: The Encyclopaedia of Design Theory >> Hadamard matrices >> Construction from Latin squares (Page 4)